# PostgreSQL partial unique index and upsert

Tags: postgresql, indexing, unique, upsert

I'm trying to do an upsert to a table that has partial unique indexes

```
create table test (
    p text not null,
    q text,
    r text,
    txt text,
    unique(p,q,r)
);

create unique index test_p_idx on test(p) where q is null and r is null;
create unique index test_pq_idx on test(p, q) where r IS NULL;
create unique index test_pr_idx on test(p, r) where q is NULL;
```

In plain terms, `p` is not null and only one of `q` or `r` can be null.

Duplicate inserts throw constraint violations as expected

```
insert into test(p,q,r,txt) values ('p',null,null,'a'); -- violates test_p_idx
insert into test(p,q,r,txt) values ('p','q',null,'b'); -- violates test_pq_idx
insert into test(p,q,r,txt) values ('p',null, 'r','c'); -- violates test_pr_idx
```

However, when I'm trying to use the unique constraint for an upsert

```
insert into test as u (p,q,r,txt) values ('p',null,'r','d') 
on conflict (p, q, r) do update 
set txt = excluded.txt
```

it still throws the constraint violation

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_pr_idx"
>   DETAIL:  Key (p, r)=(p, r) already exists.

But I'd expect the `on conflict` clause to catch it and do the update.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using an `index_predicate`?

> **index_predicate**
>   Used to allow inference of partial unique indexes. Any
>   indexes that satisfy the predicate (which need not actually be partial
>   indexes) can be inferred. Follows CREATE INDEX format.
>   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46728249/330315

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial Index not used in ON CONFLICT clause while performing an upsert in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727740/partial-index-not-used-in-on-conflict-clause-while-performing-an-upsert-in-postg)

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it's possible to use multiple partial indexes as a conflict target. You should try to achieve the desired behaviour using a single index. The only way I can see is to use a unique index on expressions:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (
    p text not null,
    q text,
    r text,
    txt text
);

create unique index test_unique_idx on test (p, coalesce(q, ''), coalesce(r, ''));
```

Now all three tests (executed twice) violate the same index:

```
insert into test(p,q,r,txt) values ('p',null,null,'a'); -- violates test_unique_idx
insert into test(p,q,r,txt) values ('p','q',null,'b');  -- violates test_unique_idx
insert into test(p,q,r,txt) values ('p',null, 'r','c'); -- violates test_unique_idx
```

In the insert command you should pass the expressions used in the index definition:

```
insert into test as u (p,q,r,txt) 
values ('p',null,'r','d') 
on conflict (p, coalesce(q, ''), coalesce(r, '')) do update 
set txt = excluded.txt;
```